# Inserting text or html into .notebook

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to insert the output of a web page into a notebook (essentially a text or html "screen capture").  No need for it to be "live", it is just there for reference.

Ideally it would appear much like it does on a web-browser.  I want it to be non-evaluatable and I don't want the front end to be trying to format it as a very error ridden Mathematica expression

(EDIT to add: creating a cell and doing "Cell->Convert To->Text Display" is a good-enough way of getting text displayed without the front end reformatting things.  I am wondering if this is the "right" way to do this or if there is a better way, especially if I'd like to have html formatting or graphics too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want the text (possibly with styles), select the text on the web page, create a Text cell in Mathematica (cmd-7 on Mac), then paste.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out the "cmd-7" equivalent on the linux version of Mathematica.  Is what you are doing equivalent to creating a cell and then doing ""Cell->Convert To->Text Display" a la the edit in my question?

Comment: @Daniel Under Windows (and probably Linux) the keyboard combination for creating new text Cell (and converting selected Cell to a text Cell) is Alt+7. You can see this combination in the `Format -> Style` menu.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know Mathematica isn't able to render HTML pages. Using [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HTML.html) you can get all kinds of things out of html based sites and files. One option is to get a text based version of the site like this:

```
Import["http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.html", "Plaintext"]
```

Comment: Yes, you can also get more structured inputs. For example if your site has tables, you can get it in lists by using "Data" or "FullData" instead of "Plaintext", if you want html source use "Source" etc.

Comment: "...Mathematica isn't able to render HTML pages..." may well end up being the answer; oh well.  In my case I can't `Import` from the website because what I am interested in is the output of a calculation (i.e. there is not a static URL for the output I want).

Comment: I like this one.  `Import["http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.\
html", "Elements"]` gives a list of options {"Data", "FullData", "Hyperlinks", "Images", "ImageURLs", \
"Plaintext", "Source", "Title", "XMLObject"}.  For example `Import["http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.\
html", "Images"]`

Comment: @Daniel There's no need to have a static URL. If your URL should contain dynamically calculated stuff then that's not too difficult to do. Example: Import["http://some.site.com/staticpart?p"<>ToString[pageNumber]]

Comment: @enedene Structured output isn't getting the OP any closer to a page render than Plaintext.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Windows (with .NET), then you could use Mathematica's NETLink functionality in conjunction with the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class to capture a screenshot of a web page:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
LoadNETType["System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat", AllowShortContext -> False]
LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState", AllowShortContext -> False]

Options[dotNetBrowserScreenshot] = {Width -> 1024, Height -> Automatic};
dotNetBrowserScreenshot[uri_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  NETBlock @ Module[{browser, bitmap, tempFile, image, bounds}
  , browser = NETNew["System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser"]
  ; browser@Width = OptionValue[Width]
  ; browser@ScrollBarsEnabled = False
  ; browser@Navigate[uri]
  ; tempFile = Close@OpenWrite[]
  ; While[browser@ReadyState =!= System`Windows`Forms`WebBrowserReadyState`Complete
    , Pause[0.05]
    ]
  ; bounds = browser@Document@Body@ClientRectangle
  ; browser@Height = OptionValue[Height] /. Automatic -> bounds@Height
  ; bitmap = NETNew["System.Drawing.Bitmap", browser@Width, browser@Height]
  ; browser@DrawToBitmap[bitmap, bounds]
  ; browser@Dispose[]
  ; bitmap@Save[tempFile, System`Drawing`Imaging`ImageFormat`Png]
  ; bitmap@Dispose[]
  ; image = Import[tempFile, "PNG"]
  ; DeleteFile[tempFile]
  ; image
  ]
```

Sample use:

[image: sample screenshot]

The complete web page can be captured by using `Height -> Automatic` (which is the default).  Note that the screenshot is being displayed at reduced magnification.

Comment: Very cool! +1. Is it possible to capture the complete web page?

Comment: @Alexey Yes it is.  I have updated the definition of `dotNetBrowserScreenshot` to automatically determine the height of the screenshot from the bounds of the HTML document.  For really large documents you can still specify explicit `Width` and `Height` options to crop the document.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to convert the web-page to PDF and then `Import` this PDF file. This method should give a vector image of the original page that looks similar to what you see in the browser.

Another possibility is to make a screenshot of that web-page in a browser and insert it in the Notebook. It is also possible to make a "screenshot" with higher resolution than your monitor has by printing the web-page on some virtual printer which supports conversion to raster formats (LEADTOOLS ePrint is one of the best).

---

**EDIT**

An interesting alternative to making screenshots by hands is to use Google Web page thumbnails service. I do not know much on this but you can get encoded into JavaScript JPEG thumbnail of any web-page with an URL like

http://www.google.com/webpagethumbnail?r=2&f=2&s=300:585&query=wolfram&hl=ru&gl=us&c=11&d=http%3A%2F%2Fintegrals.wolfram.com%2F&b=1&j=google.vs.r&a=D57

This URL gives a file with the following element:

> ["data:image/jpeg;base64,"]

(`<data>` here is an acronym for encoded JPEG image data).

We can extract `data` in *Mathematica* in the following way:

```
data = Import[
  "http://www.google.com/webpagethumbnail?r=2&f=2&s=300:585&query=\
wolfram&hl=ru&gl=us&c=11&d=http%3A%2F%2Fintegrals.wolfram.com%2F&b=1&\
j=google.vs.r&a=D57"];

imageData = 
  StringReplace[
   data, __ ~~ "[\"data:image/jpeg;base64," ~~ x__ ~~ "\"]," ~~ __ :> 
    x]
```

I do not know how to convert `imageData` further but it is just a matter of knowing of JPEG format specification...

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  It would be nice if I could just copy-paste it in, but I'll try printing to a PDF and importing that..

Comment: Depending on your browser, you may be able to find an extension that will take a screenshot of the page and put it on your clipboard.  Then just paste it into Mathematica.

Comment: Starting with Mathematica 6, you can import a base64-encoded JPEG web resource using `Import[url, {"Base64", "JPEG"}]`.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are on OS X, ctrl+shift+cmd+4 results in the cursor changing to a cross with the current coordinates next to it; selecting an arbitrary rectangular area on the screen copies it to the clipboard, from which you can paste it into mma (as a raster graphic).

Surely there exist ways of doing this in other operating systems.

Comment: Typing space after the shortcut allows you to easily select an entire window.  Note also that this only gets the portion of the page that is visible on screen.  There are other programs/browser extensions that will get the entire page, even the parts that are scrolled off-screen.